# Redis list of nested keys

Tags: list, redis, key

I have saved lists in following format in my Redis database.

> key:inner-key1:inner-key2:inner-key3

For example my database looks like this:

> A:B:X:val1
>
> A:B:Y:val2
>
> A:C:X:val3
>
> A:C:Y:val4

How can I get inner keys for key B?
I was trying to get it using
KEYS A:B:*,
but result of this are whole lines "A:B:X:val1" and "A:B:X:val2".
All I need is to get only first inner key of "A:B" in format for example [X, Y].

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Redis Hash](http://redis.io/commands#hash) to acheive the same:

Your Keys are

```
    A:B:X:val1
    A:B:Y:val2
    A:C:X:val3
    A:C:Y:val4
```

you can save your keys as

```
    HSET A:B  X val1
    HSET A:B  Y val2
    HSET A:C  X val1
    HSET A:C  Y val2
```

Now to get all keys for A:B you can do like

```
    HKEYS A:B           this will return [X Y]
```