# How to add multiple values into one key using Redis

Tags: python, redis

I have been trying to figure out how to get multiple values into a key for example:

```
{
    "fruit": {
        "tomato": {
            "Color": "red",
            "Price": "100"
        },
        "banana": {
            "Color": "yellow",
            "Price": "150"
        }
    }
}
```

For now my currently code is:

```
r = serialized_redis.MsgpackSerializedRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
r.set("fruit", {"tomato": {"Color": "red", "Price": "100"}})
r.set("fruit", {"banana": {"Color": "yellow", "Price": "150"}})
```

The problem is that everytime that I do a r.set it seems that it replaces so meaning that when I run this code it will just be set of:

```
{
    "fruit": {
        "banana": {
            "Color": "yellow",
            "Price": "150"
        }
    }
}
```

so even if I do a r.set of "tomato" it will be replaced by "banana" since its the latest one that is being SET.

My question is, how can I add it to the same Key but with different values so that everything is in the same key but it has different "furits"?

```
{
    "fruit": {
        "tomato": {
            "Color": "red",
            "Price": "100"
        },
        "banana": {
            "Color": "yellow",
            "Price": "150"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help (even though it does not use py-redis): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271372/redis-list-of-nested-keys

Comment: You can also always just store for example your dictionary as a JSON string instead.

Comment: @Timbolt yes but if I just want to be able to add one value etc as I show in example th en I might not be able to do it if I use set? - I did have hard time to understand the link you showed :(

Comment: Correct, you would need to read in the JSON to a dict, modify the dict and insert the entire JSON again. Probably not a great solution here, but still good to know since it can come in very handy to use this method in other situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use hash for that

```
hmset fruit tomato your_json_serialized_here
hmset fruit orange ...
```

you can do `hmset` with multiple fruit too like this `hmset fruit apple 1 banana 2 orange 3`

accessing data from hash with hmget is like this `hmget fruit orange banana apple`

Comment: Im not sure how that would work? I tried to do `r.hmset("fruit", {"tomato": {"Color": "red", "Price": "100"}})` but that returned `WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value` What am I missing?

Comment: you have to serialize the object or stringify it `hmset fruit tomato <the-json-stringify-of-object"`

Comment: Just a heads up that HMSET is deprecated as of version 4.0.0. HSET can be used instead:
https://redis.io/commands/hset/